# Could "super" be used inside a method of subclass to call the corresponding method of super-class without direct referencing?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I came across a usage of "super" in [a tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTJLm.png) that seemed strange. `super()` is used inside the method `get()` of the subclass to call the method `get()` of the superclass without using any accessor notations. Would that work? If yes, where can I find more references about it?

Edit:

```
class Answer {
  constructor(value) {
    this._val = value;
  }
  get() {
    return this._val;
  }
}

class FirmAnswer extends Answer {
  constructor(value) {
    super(value);
  }

  get() {
    return super() + '!!';
  }
}
var luckyAnswer = new FirmAnswer(7);
luckyAnswer.get();
```

Thanks @FlexiKling and @sorenymous for typing the code :)

Comment: It would help if you could post the actual code instead of a link to an image of it. Please [edit] your question to include it. Also link the tutorial that is the source of it.

Comment: @Bergi, It's a lot of typing :/

Comment: Doesn't matter, you still should do it. And isn't this a screenshot of text that can be copy-and-pasted from the original source?

Comment: I'd rather delete the question than typing it. It's from video.

Comment: Oh come on, it's not that much of typing… Can you link the video, please?

Comment: https://youtu.be/PMfcsYzj-9M?t=22m52s

Comment: There, I added the code. Didn't take me a minute :P

Comment: The video is from 2013. In the earlier versions of the class syntax proposal, this was possible. It was removed in [Draft Rev 28 (October 14, 2014 )](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#october_14_2014_draft_rev_28).

Comment: So, you accepted an answer that only provides information that you could have figured out yourself (by simply running the code). The other answers at least provides some background information...

Comment: s/he went through typing the whole thing to provide a piece of code for everyone to test and clear their doubt about the issue. Between experiment and theory, I chose experiment. Anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it produced a syntax error.

```
class Answer {
  constructor(value) {
    this._val = value;
  }
  get() {
    return this._val;
  }
}

class FirmAnswer extends Answer {
  constructor(value) {
    super(value);
  }

  get() {
    return super() + '!!';
  }
}
var luckyAnswer = new FirmAnswer(7);
luckyAnswer.get();
```

Console Output:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here`

Answer (score 4):

No, direct `super` calls (without a property) are only allowed in constructors, and constitute syntax errors everywhere else. It needs to be `super.get()`.

The tutorial you are referencing is from 2013. In the earlier versions of the class syntax proposal, this form was indeed possible. However, it was removed in [Draft Rev 28 (October 14, 2014 )](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#october_14_2014_draft_rev_28):

> super without an immediately following property specifier is now illegal in all MethodDefinition (no more implicit super using current method name)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, since I don't know the answer, I can't accept yours unless you could provide a reference.

Comment: Well, you could try it out in an ES6-compliant environment, check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) or have a look into [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors) :-)

Comment: Hope you don't mind my additions! Please remove or change it if you don't like it :) (and I'm sorry in that case!)

Comment: @FelixKling: Thank you, feel free to edit any of my answers :-)